# Aggregating every n columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this -

```
  A1_A A1_B A1_C A1_D B1_A B1_B B1_C B1_D C1_A C1_B C1_C C1_D 
1 0.86  0.9 0.75 0.65 0.12 0.35 0.45 0.44  0.2  0.4  0.6  0.7
2 ...
3 ...
```

I am trying to computing the mean of every 2 columns for every row using `dplyr`. The expected output:-

```
  A1_A A1_C B1_A  B1_C C1_A C1_C
1 0.88 0.70 0.23 0.445  0.3 0.65
2 ...
3 ...
```

I understand `rowsums` in basic R can do something similar. Is there a way to do it in `dplyr`?

Although, in the example here `n=2`, my actual data varies dynamically and `n` can vary accordingly. A generalized method to aggregate row-wise data from `n` columns is required.

Thanks!

**Example for n=3**

```
df <- structure(list(A1_A = 0.86, A1_B = 0.9, A1_C = 0.75, A1_D = 0.65,      
                     A1_E = 0.6, A1_F = 0.65, B1_A = 0.12, B1_B = 0.35, 
                     B1_C = 0.45, B1_D = 0.44, B1_E = 0.5, B1_F = 0.55, 
                     C1_A = 0.2, C1_B = 0.4,      C1_C = 0.6, C1_D = 0.7, 
                     C1_E = 0.75, C1_F = 0.8), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")
```

Output:

```
#   A1_A A1_D B1_A B1_D C1_A C1_D 
# 1 0.84 0.63 0.31  0.5  0.4 0.75
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput()`?

Comment: And your expected output?

Comment: Do you want the row-wise means of adjacent columns? Like `(df$A1_A + df$A1_B) / 2`? Or do you want the mean of all the values in those two columns, like `mean(c(df$A1_A, df$A1_b))`? Or something else?

Comment: I have edited the question to contain the expected output.

@GregorThomas Yes, I want row-wise means of n adjacent columns (here n=2)

Comment: Side note: It would be `rowSums` then, not `colSums`

Comment: Thanks! I'm fairly new to R.. so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way is to sum up the odd and even columns and divide it by 2.

```r
(df[seq(1, ncol(df), 2)] + df[seq(2, ncol(df), 2)])/2

#   A1_A A1_C  B1_A  B1_C C1_A C1_C
# 1 0.88  0.7 0.235 0.445  0.3 0.65
```

---

###### Generalization

- `n = 3`

```r
n <- 3
unname(sapply(seq(1, ncol(df), n), \(x) rowMeans(df[x:(x+(n-1))])))

# [1] 0.8366667 0.6333333 0.3066667 0.4966667 0.4000000 0.7500000
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to generalize this for every n columns?

Comment: @swathi.upadhya could you provide the expected output for n=3?

Comment: I have edited the question providing the the output for n=3